# Why are there no bit shifting opcodes in Ethereum?

Tags: evm, bit-manipulation

Why are there no bit shifting opcodes in Ethereum?  What's the fastest and cheapest way (in terms of gas) to implement them?

Comment: Relevant pull request: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/527

Answer (score 6):

```
x >> y = x / 2**y
x << y = x * 2**y
```

Comment: This answer can be improved if some context and description is added to explain it a little further for general audiences :)

Comment: also, is the answer to "why" A) it's not needed in EVM, or B) higher level languages are expected to provide such functions, or C) everyone that needs it should implement it?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what was the rationale behind not including bit shifting opcodes in the EVM, but (for most of the cases) they can definitely be emulated with multiplication and division. Having dedicated opcodes for them would make them faster.

- Left shift (`x << y`) is equivalent to: `x * (2 ^ y)`
- Right shift (`x >> y`) is equivalent to: `x / (2 ^ y)`

(Where `2 ^ y` means power, usually written as `2 ** y` in programming languages.)

These are known as [logical shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift). For [arithmetic shifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift) it can produce different results to what's expected.

Luckily in the EVM there is signed (`SDIV`) and unsigned division (`DIV`) so both cases of right shifts can be implemented.

If you are looking at Solidity, I'm not entirely sure which one it will use in the case of right shift.

Answer (score 5):

Shift opcodes - SHL, SHR, SAR - are a planned addition of Constantinople (expected in 2019).

See the  relevant EIP here: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-145.md

Comment: Thanks, an answer of this sort can be accepted when the EIP is implemented and more details are provided, for example how to use the new opcodes including higher-level language/s.

Comment: Are these opcodes in the EVM now?